# Mission control always popups incidentally/automatically when typing

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, mission-control, multi-touch

Recently on my MacBook Pro 2019, mission control always popups incidentally when I'm typing.

At the beginning I thought there's an issue of my trackpad since my wrists almost touch it when I'm typing and I having gesture setting to activate mission control, "swipe up with four fingers". So I turned this setting off. But the issue is still there.

Then I looked into "System preferences" to find any possible shortcuts that may activate mission control and turned them off, but none of them helped.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I am typing, mission control is still activated incidentally.

I use a MacBook Pro 2014 mid for 5 years, and never encounter this issue in all OS versions until last month I switched to a MacBook Pro 2019. The issue only happens when I am typing or using the keyboard. About 10~20 times a day.

My OS version is: `10.14.6 (18G84)`

Any help or debug suggestion are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check for hot corners

Comment: You may be accidentally pressing the F3 button when typing.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Nothing is on.

Comment: @AnExistingPerson My Touch Bar is set to displayed `f1, f2, ... keys`. I press `f3` manually, and nothing happens.

Comment: @Edityouprofile in your second Screenshot, can you try adding the default shortcut to mission control? It is Ctrl+ up arrow?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Yes, it's default to Ctrl+up. And I've also tried to bind it to some complex shortcut that may never be hit, e.g. (Ctrl + option + Command + f12), but still no help. I still have no idea what causes it activated.

Comment: Are you using any third-party shortcut tools? BetterTouchTool for example?

Comment: @japes Nope, I don't...